# In C find string and cut some symbols from left and right

Tags: c, text-parsing

Variable can contain 3-4HYTER3 (OK) or [ID] = "3-4HYTER3" (wrong)

Need cut wrong symbols in string like: [ID] = "3-4HYTER3"
Should be: 3-4HYTER3

How can find wrong string [ID] = 3-4HYTER3 and cut [ID] = "   " ?

Please, Help me!

Comment: Please give more explanation!!!

Comment: Read about [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), and look for a regular expression library that has a replace function.

Comment: Or fix the "reading" into the "variable" so that you always get the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you, you want something like -

```
const char *removeId(const char *input) {
  const char *pattern = "[ID] = \"";
  const size_t patternLen = strlen(pattern);
  if (strncmp(input, pattern, patternLen) == 0) {
    size_t outLen = strlen(input) - patternLen;
    char *out = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char *) * outLen);
    strncpy(out, input+patternLen, outLen - 1);
    out[outLen - 1] = '\0';
    return out;
  }
  return input;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const char *input = "[ID] = \"3-4HYTER3\"";
  puts(input);
  puts(removeId(input));
}
```

Output is

```
[ID] = "3-4HYTER3"
3-4HYTER3
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer about cutting the unwanted ID, if you have a large number of strings to search to identify which contain an unwanted char, such as the `=` sign in your example, you can use a simple function to search for the character in the string and take action as necessary:

```
/* char in string - returns 1 if found, 0 otherwise
   (could make (void *) and return 'p' or NULL)
*/
int
chr_in_str (char *str, char c)
{
    char *p = str;
    while (*p != '\0') {
        if (*p == c)
            return 1;
        p++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Simply pass the string and the character of interest in a test:

```
if (chr_in_str (str, '='))
    removeId (str);      // removeId from Elliots answer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define VALID_CHAR_SET "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"\
                       "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"\
                       "0123456789"\
                       "-_"

static inline bool isValidChar(char ch){
    //or use is isalnum() etc.. in <ctype.h>
    // return isalnum(ch) || ch == '-' /* ... */;
    return !!strchr(VALID_CHAR_SET, ch);//Simple implementation
}

int removeInvalidChar(char *str){
    char *to;
    int count = 0;
    for(to=str;*str;++str){
        if(isValidChar(*str))
            *to++ = *str;
        else
            ++count;
    }
    *to = '\0';
    return count;
}

int main(){
    char str[]="\"3-4HYTER3\"";
    if(removeInvalidChar(str)){
        printf("removed the invalid character.\n");
    }
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```